# No Such Element for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying a web automation script and I was able to find the name tag for the username box and based on the HTML page, I dont believe it is located in a different frame and is located in the middle of the page, so I am not sure why it isn't able to locate the element
MY CODE:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
search.send_keys("test")

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

HTML CODE:
[image: HTML code]

I have tried finding with xpath as well but no luck, any advice?

Comment: Is it possible that you are searching before the input loads? What if you sleep it for a few seconds before searching?

Comment: @marsnebulasoup how does sleep work for this ?

Comment: I mean add `time.sleep(5)` (or some such; doesn't have to be 5 seconds) before the first line here, so that the page fully loads before searching for the input box

Comment: @marsnebulasoup oh awesome it worked I didnt think of that thanks !

Comment: Great! Your code is probably searching for the input before it has been rendered by the page's internal JavaScript (or some such), so that's why you'd have to wait before searching.

Comment: Don't use `sleep`; it is wasteful. Instead of `time.sleep(5)`, execute `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` right after instantiating the driver, You will then wait for *up to* 5 seconds for the element to appear, but less if it appears sooner.